# I am trying to build a model with angular 2 having issues with them not selecting right

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to build out my html template with an interface in angular 2 to show check boxes. I want these to behave like normal check boxes where if they put a check by that value then pass that value if they put one by all then pass all countries.

here is my interface

```
export interface Sop {
    description: String; 
    country?: String[];
}
```

this is my component code

```
export class VideoFormComponent implements OnInit {
  public sop: Sop; 
   public countrys = [
        {value: 'US', display: 'US'}, 
        {value: 'UK', display: 'UK'}, 
        {value: 'JP', display: 'JP'}, 
        {value: 'CA', display: 'CA'}, 
        {value: 'All', display: 'All'}
    ]; 
  ngOnInit(){
     this.sop = {
         description: "hello",
         country: [this.countrys[4].value]
     }
  }
```

here is my html:

```
<label>Country: </label>

            <div *ngFor="let country of countrys">

                <input type="checkbox"  [name]="country.display" [(ngModel)]="sop.country"  [value]="country.value">{{country.display}}
                </div><br>
```

this displays correctly but when the page loads they are all checked. and when I try to un-select one they all un-select I am fairly new to angular 2. I want all the be checked by default but I also want them to be able to select or un-select whenever they want too. I do want a check to be required though but I guess if they un-check all of them I can make "" = all countries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all checked because you have this binding `[(ngModel)]="sop.country"`.

This says that; this input elements model is `sop.country` and since `sop.country` has a "truthy" value ( `country: [this.countrys[4].value]` ), they are all checked.

And you binded all of them to the same model so that's why they all behave the same.

You'll probably want something more like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/SvVEqDwDitLSWr3KWXeL?p=preview

Comment: dude that is exactly what I am missing thank you very much... you are awesome

Comment: @JoshuaDeshazer Glad I could help sir.